# Calculating redis max memory when running multiple redis instance in same machine

Tags: redis, operating-system

I want to set up a Redis cluster with 6 Redis instances with 3 machines(so 2 Redis instances with one machine) each with 32GB memory, 8 core CPU.
I am not sure how many bytes will be enough for Redis max-memory config.

1. Considering 4GB memory is used by OS, I guess 28GB is left for the user processes.
   And since running 2 Redis instances in a multi-core environment, I think I should set 14GB max memory config value for each Redis instance because both processes are both up and running simultaneously. But I am not sure. Which max memory value is correct for this case?
2. I remember that the operating system saves page tables for each process, and loads and unloads the process's page table to physical memory when the core works on the process. So in the case of a single-core CPU environment with 32GB memory, is it ok to set 28GB max memory for each instance, since there will be only one process running concurrently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, multi Redis instance in one machine is not recommended. Because of the L3 cache of CPU can not work effectively. If you want Redis run more effectively, you can bind Redis instances to different cpu cores mannually.

Then, the max memory.

1. if you use `RDB` for data save. The answer is 7GB. The `BGSAVE` thread will fork from main thread, the `COW(Copy-on-write)` will copy page tables when new  write comming, so it will use another 7GB for maximum. Two Redis instance will  cost 28GB.
2. single-core CPU environment is not friendly for Redis. I suggest two-core. The max memory is 14GB.

Comment: So if using aof or configure no data save, it will be ok for each redis to use 14GB of max memory. For the second answer, i think you suggest two core in case RDB data save is used. 
Assume RDB back up is not used,
1. Is it ok to redis in single core cpu environment?
2. If running two redis in single core environment(no backup, 14GB each out of total 32GB), i think there must be cost for context switching and memory load, unload. Is there any performance stats that i can compare the performance in multi-core and single-core environment?

Comment: and would that be same for running 1 master and 1 slave instance in same machine?
(Machine1 - Master1 Slave2,
Machine2 - Master2 Slave3,
Machine3 - Master3 Slave1)

Comment: if configure not data save, then it is ok for 14GB and single core. if configure aof, then aof will fork `bgrewriteaof` thread, two cores are recommended, the max memory for aof mode depends on you configuration of aof rewrite min size and percentage. if you do not have large amount of keys, then 14GB is also ok.

Comment: it is same for master and slave, they all need to run `bgsave` or `bgrewriteaof` thread for data save.

Comment: Thanks. And this question isn't actually about redis, how will os manage memory if i run 2 redis instance each with 28GB ram when total is 32GB?
Will it put some part in swap, and load and unload them depending on process usage?

Comment: yes, the memory will swap. you should avoid that configuration.